# Django CMS and Rosetta: Can't get template messages translated

Tags: django, internationalization, django-templates, django-cms, django-rosetta

Is there any know issue about using Django CMS and Django Rosetta together.
I cant get the "static" template messages translated although it appears correctly translated in the Rosetta interface.

All the dynamic content is correctly translated. Only the one I´ve set up around the `{% trans 'blabla' %} does not work.

Comment: Have you gone through the usual checklist? - 1) translation is actually in django.po file 2) translation is not marked fuzzy, 3) updated translation file is compiled, 4) server has been restarted

Comment: I have the same problem, and I checked the classic 4 points.

Comment: I still could not manage this to work either...

Answer (score 2):

Gotcha!

Just add in settings.py

`LOCALE_PATHS = (BASE_DIR + "/locale/",)`

It worked for me.