# Rosetta can't find anything to translate "Nothing to translate!"

Tags: python, django, django-rosetta

Versions:

- Python 3.5.1
- django 1.10
- django-rosetta 0.7.13

I followed [the rosetta tutorial](http://django-rosetta.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html). After creating some sentences to translate in a template using `{% trans "sentence" %}` (and `{% load i18n %}`), and running `django-admin`'s `makemessages` and `compilemessages`, rosetta still cannot find anything to translate:

> Nothing to translate!
>
> You haven't specified any languages in your settings file, or haven't
>   yet generated a batch of translation catalogs.
>
> Please refer to Django's I18N documentation for a guide on how to set
>   up internationalization for your project.

Notes:

- I had to solve some other bugs along the way. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44519301/cannot-access-rosetta).
- I looked in the locale folder and the .po and .mo files are there, and they look correct (i.e. have the sentences I made in the template). Here's the .po file.

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2017-06-13 13:31+0200\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"Language: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#: templates/www/batch.html:8
msgid "(mother) and"
msgstr ""

#: templates/www/batch.html:8
msgid "(father)"
msgstr ""
```

- I haven't used any fuzzy or laziness, except in one place needed to avoid an error (see below). But it didn't work before I did that either.
- I tried adding the desired language to `settings.py`'s `LANGUAGES` list. No effect, except I had to solve [yet another bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157882/translation-infrastructure-cannot-be-initialized-before-the-apps).
- I did add the `LOCALE_PATHS` suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439031/django-cms-and-rosetta-cant-get-template-messages-translated).
- I did restart the server a bunch of times.
- I'm running the server via `runserver` (via PyCharm). Local development.

I can't think of or find anything more to try.

Comment: in which language you want translation? 
'django-admin makemessages --all' use this for make other languages translation

Comment: The files are there already. It's not a problem with makemessages.

Comment: I managed to solve the issue in that eventually my translations started appearing under third party. However, I have no idea what was the causal factor, so I can't answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. create `locale` directory in project root
2. run `django-admin makemessages -l fa -i myenv`

Comment: [Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/248627)